# Как посчитать кол-во цифр дробной части?(написать функцию) Язык: си

Tags: c

Надо посчитать кол-во цифирок после запятой. Есть недоработанный код:

```
int k(double acc) {
    int count = 0;
    while (acc != 0) {
        acc = acc/10;
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Намек: https://ideone.com/IJ55VY

Answer (score 0):

если я не путаю, то только если дробная часть может быть записана в виде `1/(2^n)` можно подсчитать какое-то конечное число цифр дробной части иначе кол-во цифр дробной части будет равно максимальному кол-ву цифр, которые поддерживает дробь (для float это в районе 7, для double - в районе 15)

- это связано с тем, что числа хранятся в двоичном виде, а перевод конечной дробной части из двоичной в десятичную систему исчисления и наоборот дает бесконечную дробную часть

т.е. какое-то число вида

```
const float value = 1.3;
```

на самом деле будет равно `1.29999998`

Comment: Да, вы правы. Там действительно дробная часть записана в виде 1/(2^n).На самом деле код намного обширней, и эта функция лишь малая его часть.

Answer (score 0):

```c
int count_float_dig(double acc)
{
    int count = 0;
    int integer = (int)acc; //берем целую часть числа
    while (integer != acc) //сравниваем целую часть числа с самим числом
    {
        acc *= 10; //если нужно, то добавляем в целую часть числа новую цифру
        count++;
        integer = (int)acc;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Хотел испытать - https://ideone.com/3wcEki Поясните, что я сделал не так? почему не работает?